# Android Reading file, error

Tags: java, android

FIXED THAT ALONE
there were lots of problems, i noticed them step by step with debugging, thanks anyway (:

i have some weird error, the application just crashes.
The problem is in this code:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(sdcard,"Potato/Users.txt");

////////// ------ CHECK IF USER EXISTS BEFORE REGISTER -----------


    //Get the text file


    //Read text from file
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');


            int start = text.indexOf("{");
            int end = text.indexOf("}");
            login50 = text.substring(start + 1, end - start - 1);

            int start2 = text.indexOf("[");
            int end2 = text.indexOf("]");
            password50 = text.substring(start + 1, end - start - 1);

            text=null;

            if(login50.equals(user))
            {
                annoying=false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //You'll need to add proper error handling here
    }
    /////////////////////////// ----- DONE --------------
```

I did in my application simple register, 2 fields: login and password.
The txt file looks like that:

Login {example} ; Password [example]

The code is taking string between {} as login and checking if what you wrote on textfield equals this string..
if yes, don't let create new account(annoying=false)
All this on a loop for whole txt file, to check if what you wrote on textfield, is existing user or not.

The application working to create new user, but if you write name as existing user, application crashes.

And yes i have all the permissions on manifest file (:

Help? ):

Comment: Is there any error in logcat? Any stacktrace?

Comment: WE NEED YOUR _LOGCAT_ !

Answer (score 0):

Try  changing

```
String line;
```

to

```
String line="";
```

Comment: Come on, how could that change anything?

Comment: @FD_, I am not sure, if String line; allocate memory to line. Does it?Pls, let me know. Thnks